# Kivy Adding Widget to a screen

Tags: python, kivy

This seems to be a silly question. But I have a widget that I want to add to a screen called GameScreen.

This is my Python code:

```
class WelcomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

class BasicScreen(Screen):
    pass

class GameScreen(Screen):
    parent = Widget()
    game =  ShootingGame()
    parent.add_widget(game)
    Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0 / 60.0)
    # return parent

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(WelcomeScreen(name='welcome'))
sm.add_widget(BasicScreen(name='basic'))
sm.add_widget(GameScreen(name='game'))

class ShootingApp(App):
    def build(self):
        print(sm.current)
       return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    ShootingApp().run()
```

And this is my kivy code:

```
<WelcomeScreen>:
Button:
    text: "Learn about haptic illusions"
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 500, 70
    pos: 100, 200
    font_size: 30
    on_release: app.root.current = "basic"

Button:
    text: "Play our game"
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 500, 70
    pos: 100, 100
    font_size: 30
    on_release: app.root.current = "game"

<BasicScreen>:
name: "basic"

<GameScreen>:
name: "game"
```

The error I am getting is this. And I think this is because I already defined a parent for the widget game. However, I need that parent because the game widget uses width and height values of its parent (e.g., self.parent.width). Is there any workaround for this so that the game widget can be nested in a parent and add the parent to the screen?

```
kivy.uix.widget.WidgetException: Cannot add <Screen name='game'>, it already has a parent <kivy.uix.widget.Widget object at 0x1093dc8d8>
```

Thanks guys!!

Comment: the parent property is automatically set to the parent when a child is added to another widget , http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html?highlight=parent#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.parent 
so in your code you overide the parent property and set it to widget(), and when you add GameScreen to sm , it raise an Exception that the GameScreen already have a parent , simply add_widget(game) would work

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This makes sense. But doing add_widget(game) is giving me an of "name 'add_widget' is not defined"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
class GamesScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GameScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.game = ShootingGame()
        self.add_widget(self.game)
        clock.schedule_interval(self.game.update, 1.0 / 60.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like what's happening is that you attempt to give `GameScreen` a parent TWICE. Once when telling it it's parent is `Widget()`, and again when you add it to the `ScreenManager`(which would make `sm` it's parent). Whichever of them is executed first(I think the `parent = Widget()` line from looking at the Exception) is causing the error when you try it the second time.